# Outlook - warning if email has been sent before this month

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to set up a code so when I send an email from a template to someone (often if I'm contacted with the same over and over again) it automatically checks if I already sent it to them within the last month.

Right now I have made a warning system for myself, that shows a message box when I send the email:

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(Item.Body, "A string in my template email") Then
        If MsgBox("Have you sent this already this month?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The downside is that I manually have to check whether or not I already sent it to the specific receiver.
Is it possible to make it in a way so it sends it if i haven't sent it within the last month and warns me if I already sent it out within the last month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all of your sent emails in `"Sent Items"` box and check using `InStr()` and `DateDiff()` functions for the content and date since sending each.

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal thisItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object

    Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' set folder to Sent Items box
    Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Sent Items")

    ' iterate thru emails
    For Each Item In folder.Items
        ' check subject content & date difference
        If InStr(Item.subject, "your string here") And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
            ' added this part
            If MsgBox("You have already sent this email this month, do you want to send again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
                ' cancel the email
                Cancel = True
            End If
            Exit For      
        End If    
    Next

End Sub
```

Also, here is how I have done this before with shared inboxes in my situation:

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set firstFolder = olNs.Folders("UAT-COE Support Intake Box") ' name of my shared inbox
Set olFolder = firstFolder.Folders("Inbox")
```

You may have to do the same, but change `"UAT-COE Support..."` with your shared inbox name. Also will need to change `"Inbox"` with `"Sent Items"` or `"Sent"`.

Once you have `olFolder` set to the correct Sent box, you can replace it with folder in the above code `For each Item in olFolder.Items`